# Configuration of Prettier in vscode with Angular

Tags: angular, typescript, prettier

I want my editor to format constructor parameters that's are injected into constructor into one line per parameter.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to do this for all arguments. You can use eslint rule:

`function-paren-newline: ["error", { "minItems": 3 }]`

https://eslint.org/docs/rules/function-paren-newline